# WCF, self hosting - windows service ,implementing a custom claim authorization policy , no IIS

Tags: c#, wcf-security

can i implement a custom claim authorization policy for self hosted WCF service (in windows service) without the need for iis installation? 
what is the configuration i need for that.
is there is any other way to manage authorization outside of WCF service with custom class (as i dont want to interfere the code with authorization checks)
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 3.5 or 4.0?

Here is a screencast about self-hosting that may lead you in the right direction:
[Self Hosting Screencast](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Self-hosting-WCF-Services/)

Comment: i did not ask about the self host magic thing ( i know this very good ... )
i asked about implementing authorization without the need for iis (role manager) or imperative \ declarative authorization checks inside my service.

Comment: i think this can be the answer: 
Create a Custom Authorization Manager for a Service:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731774.aspx